# Two ramified covers $\Rightarrow$ reducible ramification divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X,X',X''$ be algebraic varieties and let $X''\to X'$ and $X'\to X$ be two ramified covers. Is the ramification divisor of the composition $X''\to X'\to X$ reducible?

Comment: Certainly not in this generality, e.g. it won't happen if both morphisms are étale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=X'=X''=\Bbb{A}^1$ be the affine line, and let the two covers be $z \mapsto z^2$. Their composite is the (ramified) cover $z \mapsto z^4$, and the ramification divisor of this morphism is supported at $0$ only. This shows in particular that the ramification divisor can be irreducible.

Comment: Ah, that's true. Is there some hypothesis I'm missing that will ensure that the ramification divisor is reducible though?

Comment: e.g., if the ramification divisor is reduced?

Comment: Dear @hilbert, I know of no condition which will ensure reducibility of the ramification divisor. However, since reducedness is a condition on the structure sheaf of the divisor, and irreducibility a purely topological notion, I don't believe the two are related by any means.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer!